# Best practice - inherited variables set in derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

I have an abstract class containing methods that rely on class-level variables. However, the values of those variables are set in the classes that inherit from the abstract.

I've written this so that the variables are set in the constructor - it seemed by far the neatest thing to do. But I just feel vaguely uncomfortable about it - they look like they ought to be abstract properties instead. I just can't put my finger on why I feel that way.

Here's a simplified example of what I've actually done:

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected string itemType;
}

public class TestClass1 : TestBase
{
    public TestClass1()
    {
        itemType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestClass1.ItemType"];
    }
}

public class TestClass2 : TestBase
{
    public TestClass2()
    {
        itemType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestClass2.ItemType"];
    }
}
```

So, the questions are:

1) Is this bad practice?

2) If so, why, and what's better?

3) This is a test class, used for regression testing rather than being deployed anywhere. Is there a good reason to set my class-level variables in config as in the example, or is it okay to hard-code them? I always tend toward config by default.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: I feel very comfortable with your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data along to the right constructor(s):

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected string itemType;    // can now become 'readonly`

    protected TestBase(string keyName)
    {
       itemType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyName];
    }
}

public class TestClass1 : TestBase
{
    public TestClass1() : base("TestClass1.ItemType")
    {
        //itemType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestClass1.ItemType"];
    }
}
```

This way it's more consistent and not so easy to forget an item.

Answer (score 1):

1: there's a lot to be said for fields always being `private`; other access *can work* though.

2:

The most common approach here is probably:

```
public abstract class TestBase {
    private string itemType;
    protected TestBase(string itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }
}
public class TestClass1 : TestBase {
    public TestClass1() : base(
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestClass1.ItemType"])
    {}
}
```

but you could also just use:

```
public abstract class TestBase {
    protected string ItemType {get;set;}
    // or:
    // public string ItemType {get;protected set;}
}
public class TestClass1 : TestBase {
    public TestClass1() {
       ItemType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestClass1.ItemType"];
    }
}
```

If the app-setting name always relates to the type, you could also perhaps use some reflection:

```
public abstract class TestBase {
    private string itemType;
    protected TestBase() {
        itemType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
            GetType().Name + ".ItemType";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me better way is to declare abstract property. If you forget to set property in inherited class then compiler will remind you.

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected abstract string ItemType {get;}
}

public class TestClass1 : TestBase
{
    protected override string ItemType 
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestClass1.ItemType"];}
    }
}
```